# NodeJS Express require and initiation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am learning NodeJS and Express and then I am stuck at how require works.

I have the main file as **server.js** and another test file as **test.js**.

*[ server.js ]*

```
var express=require('express');

//Include Routes
var rTest=require('./routes/test');

//Express Application COnfiguration
var app=express();

var port=process.env.PORT||3000;
var router=express.Router();    

//Index
router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.json({message:'Welcome to Index!'});

});    

app.use('/api/t',rTest); //Test    

app.listen(port);
```

*[ routes/test.js ]*

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();

    router.route('/')
        .get(function(req,res){
            res.send('Now Test Running OK!');
        });

    module.exports=router;
```

The code works as expected - going to *`http://localhost:3000/api/t`* prints the 'Now .. ' message. So my question is, why am I not creating the express app again in test.js while am certainly referencing the router from express.Router()?

This gets more confusing when I am trying to create a CRUD with mongoose. Why do I have to reference mongoose module and the schema in the test router file but do not have to establish the connection as I have done in the main server.js file.

So far I have understood the fact the require is actually local to the module I am using in, which actually makes sense as I have to reference the dependency modules every-time I need them in the other modules. But I do not have to establish the connection again in route files, don't have to listen to a certain port in the route files, use body-parser ( when I am using it) in the route files.

Any pointers will help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require()` loads a module of code and returns whatever was assigned to `module.exports` inside the module.  In general modules should be written so that loading them does not actually create anything, but rather just returns things in the exports that allow the caller to do stuff with the module.  That is, indeed, what the express module does.

In the case of the `express` module, it returns a constructor function that can be called to create an express application as you are doing in `server.js` with `app = express()`.  You are not doing that in `routes/test.js` so you aren't creating another express application there.

Note, since functions are objects in Javascript, the constructor function that the express module returns can also have its own properties such a the `express.Router` property which you are using in `routes/test.js`.

As for your mongoose question, I don't quite follow what you're asking there.  If you show us that particular code, we can likely comment further on that issue.

The methods in your route files are passed `req` and `res` arguments that are created by Express as part of handling an incoming HTTP request.  It doesn't matter which file those methods are located in.  The way Express works is that the incoming http connection is passed through the various Express middleware steps and turned into `request` and `response` objects which are then passed down to the routers to figure out which specific handlers should process that particular request.

If you are using the `body-parser` or `cookie-parser` middleware in Express (or any other middleware functionality), then those middleware steps will have already been executed before the request is passed to any router.  If what those middleware steps do is create properties on the `request` object (which is a common approach), then that data will be on the `request` object that is passed to your route handler.  You don't have to do anything special for that to happen in your routes module other than register your route handlers.  That's how Express and its middleware work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborated answer. Well it all sums up.
What I was asking about the mongoose questions was that I was establishing the connection in the **server.js** file as "mongoose.connect('mongodb://usr:pwd@localhost:27017/testdb'); " but I dont have to establish this again in the test.js router where I am manipulating data using a **test** schema. I guess the connection is being made before it reaches the router and hence when I call *<schema>.find()*, the existing connection is being used?